# Error on Model:all() in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, laravel-5

can you help me out?

I'm just starting up with laravel 5 and can't get this simple Model:all() to work. I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong, but I can't find out what.

Here's what I have:

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');
```

Partner.php

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Partner extends Model {
    protected $table = 'tab_parceiro';
    protected $fillable = '';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $primaryKey = 'codigo';
}
```

PageController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class PageController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $partners = \App\Partner::all();

        //return view('index', compact('partners'));
    }

}
```

The error:

```
[2015-03-14 12:50:22] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/storage/framework/compiled.php:9360
```

Table

```
| tab_parceiro | CREATE TABLE `tab_parceiro` (
  `CODIGO` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NOME` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENDERECO` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TELEFONE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SITE` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONTATO` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OBS` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CODIGO`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

The view actually doesn't matter, because the error occurs before the view is called.

Comment: You're passing string ``'partners'`` instead of ``$partners`` variable.

Comment: As I stated in the end, that call to the view doesn't matter, because the error occurs before that, in the Partner::all() line (that's why it's commented). Also, I'm not passing the string as a variable, I'm compacting it, which works.

Comment: @limonte that line is commented out. it won't have any effect in the flow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$fillable` has to be an **array** not a string:

```
protected $fillable = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

I put some example attributes (`foo` and `bar`) in there because an empty array is the default and you don't have to specify it at all. Anyways, the equivalent to your empty string would be:

```
protected $fillable = [];
```

Comment: I think it must be `protected $fillable = [];`

Comment: @HakanAktaş Yes but an empty array is the default so it makes no sense to specify it at all...

Comment: That what it! I knew it was something pretty stupid that I wasn't seeign. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
protected $fillable = '';
```

but it accepts array so it should be

```
 protected $fillable = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fillable should look like this:

```
protected $fillable = ['NOME', 'ENDERECO', 'TELEFONE', 'EMAIL', 'SITE', 'CONTATO','OBS'];
```

NB: Nothing is wrong with using uppercase table column names but i do suggest lowercase as a good convention.

Comment: Yeah I know about lowercase in table names, but it's another system that adds data into this tables, so, I have no control over it. Thanks.